# GMSAutocompleteViewController swift [GooglePlaces]

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I was wondering if there is any other way (some hack/trick) to change the layout/theme of *NavigationBar* and *SearchBar* without using `appearance()` in **GMSAutocompleteViewController**? I want to avoid using that because for example if I change the *NavigationBar* tint (background) or *SearchBar* text color using `appearance()`, it changes for all viewController inside the app.

Here is the official documentation from google: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#customize_text_and_background_colors

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can reset the `NavigationBar` setting inside its delegate method or you can make the superclass of each and every controller in your app which is the subclass of `UIViewController`, where you can set the required settings.

Comment: @vaibhav you mean change it with `appearance()` and in the cancel method, reset the navigationBar?

Comment: yes, something like ..

Comment: there is no street forward solution, what you need to do is to change it using appearance then reset the navigation bar again once it finish